# MariaDB unknown syntax error. Making a simple table

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariasql

I cannot find whats wrong with my single table making sql code. The 'user' that it is referencing does exist. The error I receive
is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1 in file: 'project.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (
>       id          integer(11)     Primary Key auto_increment,
>       ordertyp' at line 1

here is my code for the table:

```
create table order (
    id          integer(11)     Primary Key auto_increment,
    ordertype   varchar(255)    not null,
    timePlaced  timestamp       not null,
    buyUser     varchar(25),
    sellUser    varchar(25),
    foreign key(buyUser) references user(username),
    foreign key(sellUser) references user(username)
);
```

Anything helps, just looking for a simple syntax fix, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote your table name if it collides with a keyword, or contains special characters:

```sql
create table `order` (...)
```

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: Ok, I really don't know why I didn't have to do that before. In the same file I created tables without quoting the table name. Super weird stuff, but thank you!

Comment: because `order` is a reserved keyword. `ORDER BY ...`

Comment: @MatthewJacobsen - if you quote the table name you'll have to quote it everywhere it gets used, which gets really old really fast. I suggest you change the name of the table to something like `orders`.

Comment: Awesome, that answers my question and clears up some confusion. I didn't know order was a keyword

Comment: @MatthewJacobsen it's used to order (yes) the result of a `SELECT` query